# xcode 7 / iOS 9 / iPhone 6 sim: why extra padding to left of UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, xcode7

See screenshot below from iPhone 6 simulation run.  I've set suggested constraints.  I've cleared constraints and reset them.  None of those help -- there is still padding on the left of the table cells, and it appears the table itself overreaches the bottom border of the screen.  What is going on?

Note that I am using "Compact Width / Regular Height" in Xcode storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set `separatorInsets` and `layoutMargins` of the table view?

Comment: No.  Looking at the storyboard in Xcode 7, I believe this margin on the left (and none on the right) is the default setup for UITableView cells.  That is, in the storyboard, if you add a UITableViewCell to a UITableView, the bottom gray line extends to the far right of the screen, but not the far left.  I'll post an answer in the next day or so if no one can offer a better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small left-margin before each horizontal bar between the `UITableViewCell`s in the `UITableView`.  Looking at the prototype cell for a `UITableViewCell` in one of my storyboards, I believe this left-margin is baked into the cell by default.  I do not know if it is adjustable.